# Maximum error in Encoder when discrete sample interval is 2 ms

Tags: control-engineering

I am using an encoder having 1000 pulse in one revolution in both edges configuration. I used one method in which number of pulse is counted. What is the error in this case?
Another method is alternative approach to Quadrature encoder module where pulse duration is measured. But here we have only 69 pulse per revolution. Here clock cycle frequency is 7.38 MHz. In this case what is the error?

Comment: Do you mean what's the sensitivity? The error is the difference between desired and measured values, and can't be calculated using the information provided

Comment: Can you tell me which another parameter you require for calculation.

Comment: Can you tell me if error is what you’re really looking for?

Comment: Caution re measuring time between encoder transitions; specifically, do *not* assume that either different channels or edges act the same. Time (e.g.) rising A to next rising A. We learned this the hard way in grad school. (You can do all four in parallel in today's FPGA/CPLDs.) But now you have velocity-dependent latencies.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on readout type of readout, for the 1000 pulse, if you read both edges (x2), you have position error of at worst 1/2000 of revolution, or 0.18 degree for sufficiently low speeds. For speeds up to 15 RPM. When exceeding that speed, your readout becomes completely worthless - error value becoming arbitrarily big, as your sample readouts start skipping gaps. Also, obviously, this is an unidirectional solution; rotation can't reverse.

If instead of sampling/polling you use interrupts on one edge (x1) at much higher polling frequency but with max 2ms per interrupt, you can double the RPM, halving the accuracy - 1/1000 of revolution up to 30RPM. At least exceeding that will cap the error to sane values (readouts will be between 15 and 30RPM and consistent enough that with smart software that detects exceeding the 30RPM you can even keep increasing the speed, halving the accuracy at each 30RPM increment). You may use interrupts on both edges, which would improve readouts, but the edge detection unit must operate faster than your readout subsystem - to retrigger on two subsequent identical edges.

The quadrature encoder can be polled in 4x mode or use interrupts in 1x and 2x modes. So, 1/138, 1/69 and 1/276 rotation or 2.6 (x4), 5.2 (x1) or 1.3 (x2) degree *at worst*; linearly dropping with speed reduced from the cap.

But are you sure you didn't confuse units? 7.38 Hz is something terribly low. At the fastest you'd have ridiculous caps of 6.4 RPM at 1x, 3.2 at 2x and 1.6RPM at 4x where your solution breaks down. And you may either try supporting higher speeds at cost of accuracy, or bidirectionality, but not both.

Comment: Sorry it is 7.38 MHz. I corrected it. And here after taking both edges (x2) pulse count is 1000 pulse. Another thing is I used hall sensor output of hall sensors having total pulse 69. In this case I used alternative module of QEI.

Comment: @aman2909: "pulses per revolution" in datasheets is always given in complete cycles - 1/2 the number of edges for standard, 1/4 for quadrature encoder; when describing your setup you give the datasheet number, and readout method (x2, x4, + timing). Regardless, double or halve relevant entries for valid values.

Comment: You are talking about sensitivity, not error here - even with no skipped steps, if there is backlash in the connection to the encoder there could be a significant error

Comment: @JonathanRSwift: The "industrial" encoders I encountered have no backlash whatsoever - tight bearings and metal disk firmly fixed to a steel axis. Any possible backlash would come from strong mechanical loads they aren't meant to carry - bad device design. In case of open encoders (gap optocouplers) this all comes from mechanics you use for the disk, and is result of your own mechanical design. The only type that would have any sort of inherent error resulting from design are the turn-dial type, to be moved by hand with a knob - and there it really doesn't matter.

Comment: You’re missing my point I’m afraid - “error” is the difference between the actual position and the desired position of a thing. I was talking about backlash between the thing and the encoder, not internal to the encoder itself. To talk about the amount of error that the encoder has is misleading - you may have said what OP wanted to know, but it hasn’t answered his question, *as written*. I’ve asked him to clarify, but not had a response yet.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift: In that case it's completely implementation-dependent. And the asker didn't provide nearly any details to even approach answering that.